# Undetermined Coefficients Complex Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification, trigonometry, complex-numbers

I am trying to solve

> $$y'' + 7y' + 10y = -4\sin(3t)$$

via the complex method of undetermined coefficients.  I have already solved it via the trigonometric method and obtained 
$$y = \frac{42\cos(3t) - 2\sin(3t)}{221}.$$

The ODE is equivalent to $y'' + 7y' + 10y = -4\text{Im}(e^{3ti})$.  Since $Im()$ is homogeneous of degree $1$, we should be able to simply move the constants obtained taking exponential derivatives outside of the $\text{Im}()$; thus the guess $y_p = a\text{Im}(e^{3ti})$ is a form replicated under differentiation.  Plugging this guess into 
$$y'' + 7y' + 10y = -4\text{Im}(e^{3ti})$$ yields 
$$(a + 21ai)\text{Im}(e^{3ti}) = -4\text{Im}(e^{3ti}),$$
so $a = \frac{42i - 2}{221}$.  This means $y_p = \frac{42\sin(3t)i - 2\sin(3t)}{221}$, which is not quite correct, as $\sin(\theta)i$ is not the the same as $\cos(\theta)$.  What went wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the complex approach we should find a complex function $z_p$ such that $$z_p'' + 7z_p' + 10z_p = -4e^{3ti}.$$ 
Then, by letting $y_p=\text{Im}(z_p)$, we get
$$y_p'' + 7y_p' + 10y_p = \text{Im}(-4e^{3ti})=-4\sin(3t).$$ 
We have that $z_p(t)=ae^{3ti}$ for some $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and therefore
$$-9ae^{3ti}+21iae^{3ti}+10ae^{3ti}=-4e^{3ti}\implies a=\frac{-4}{1+21i}=\frac{-4}{1+21i}=\frac{-2+42i}{221}$$
(the same of your computation). Hence
$$y_p=\text{Im}(z_p)=\text{Im}\left(\frac{-2+42i}{221}\cdot (\cos(3t)+i\sin(3t))\right)
=\frac{42\cos(3t)-2\sin(3t)}{221}$$
which is exactly what you obtained by using the real approach.

Comment: Can you explain why my complex solution breaks down?  Since $y_p'' + 7y_p' + 10y_p = -4\text{Im}(e^{3ti})$ and $\text{Im}(e^{3ti})$ is proportional to its own derivative, it seems that $y_p = a\text{Im}(e^{3ti})$ (where $a$ turns out to be $\frac{-2+42i}{221}$) should be valid.

Comment: By letting $y_p = a\text{Im}(e^{3ti})=a\sin(3t)$, you got that $y'_p = 3ia\text{Im}(e^{3ti})=3ia\sin(3t)$, which is wrong!

Comment: @user10478 Is it clear now? Further doubts?

Comment: Almost, I've boiled it down to a new question:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3344351/linearity-and-homogeneity-of-re-and-im

Comment: @user10478 $\text{Im}()$ is linear with respect to  $\mathbb{R}$ but not with respect to $\mathbb{C}$. Here $a$ is complex so $\text{Im}(ae^{3ti})\not=a\text{Im}(e^{3ti})$.

Comment: Okay, actually I think I moved an $i$ illegally rather than $a$, but it all makes sense now, ty.